# Is there a way to ignore parse error in KConfig file for Nuttx make menuconfig setup

Tags: makefile, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

Using `menuconfig` for nuttx development.

Was trying to do below for custom board setup:

```
if ARCH_BOARD_FOO
source "configs/FOO/Kconfig"
endif
```

Problem here, I would like to have some permission control for `FOO` directory. So not all users can see it.

However, kconfig language seems will always parse the file no matter the if condition is true or not. Therefore this causing make `menuconfig` could not open for users do not have permission of `FOO` directory.

Anyone know solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a custom board configuration.  Then your board directory can lie inside or outside of the NuttX source tree.  In either case, it will not be visible to the configuration system.  you would configure this like:

```
CONFIG_ARCH_BOARD_CUSTOM=y
CONFIG_ARCH_BOARD_CUSTOM_NAME="myboard"
CONFIG_ARCH_BOARD_CUSTOM_DIR="/home/users/me/myboard"
... and other options ...
```

In the above example, the board directory lies outside of the NuttX source tree and is an absolute path.  The board configuration could also lie inside of the NuttX and the path may be specified as relative to the top-level directory with:

```
CONFIG_ARCH_BOARD_CUSTOM_DIR_RELPATH=y
```

For example:

```
CONFIG_ARCH_BOARD_CUSTOM_DIR="configs/FOO"
CONFIG_ARCH_BOARD_CUSTOM_DIR_RELPATH=y
```

Now if CONFIG_ARCH_BOARD_CUSTOM=y is not defined, there is no way to access /home/users/me/myboard or configs/FOO from the configuration system.

This works because the custom board Kconfig file will be linked to configs/dummy/Kconfig in the custom configuration with CONFIG_ARCH_BOARD_CUSTOM=y.  Otherwise configs/dummy/Kconfig will be linked to an empty configuration to satisfy the configuration system.

Answer (score 0):

In order to ignore the error, you could use:

```
if ARCH_BOARD_FOO
-source "configs/FOO/Kconfig"
endif
```